# ES6 class methods not returning anything inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, function, return, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

For some reason the method `getTwo()` inside the `PollClass` won't return `2` but `undefined`. If I put the `return` statement outside the `.forEach()` loop a value does get returned however.

```
class Poll {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.nums = [1, 2, 3];
  }

  getTwo() {
    this.nums.forEach(num => {
      if (num === 2) return num;
    })
  }
}

const newPoll = new Poll('random name');
console.log(newPoll.getTwo()); // returns undefined, not 2
```

Is this an issue with closure, ES 6, or a whole other issue?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to return if `this.nums` has no 2, or if it has more than just one 2. In any case, though, you better use `.some` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: `forEach` won't return anything. It's not a `for` loop

Comment: *"Is this an issue with closure, ES 6, or a whole other issue?"* Neither. Inner functions cannot make the outer function return something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An arrow function is still a function, and you're only returning from the forEach callback function, not from getTwo, you have to return from the `getTwo` function as well.

It's not quite clear why you would use a loop to check for something in that way, but the concept would be something like

```
getTwo() {
    var n = 0;
    this.nums.forEach(num => {
      if (num === 2) n = num;
    })
    return n; // returns something from getTwo()
  }
```

Comment: While this will work, it is still suboptimal as it will continue looping even after a `2` has been found. Depending on what the OP wants the behavior to be, either a traditional `for` loop or `find` would be better options.

Comment: @JustinNiessner - sure, `Array.some`, `Array.find`, `Array.indexOf`, and a bunch of other array methods could be useful here, but it's not clear what the OP wants, for instance `Array.some` will return a boolean.

Comment: `return this.nums.indexOf(2) !== -1` would by far be the easiest though, if it's just supposed to check if that number exists in the array.

Answer (score 4):

As **adeneo** mentioned, you must return from the `getTwo` function to achieve what you want. Returning from the callback passed into `forEach`, regardless if its an arrow function or not, doesn't return from `forEach` itself.

Alternatively to `forEach`, you can use `find` which you can write in less code and return directly:

```
getTwo() {
  return this.nums.find(num => num === 2);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the find method, and this code saves me a lot of headache trying to fumble with an index value so I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to help mate